# How to hide a swiftUI view by touching anywhere outside of it

Tags: swift, swiftui, view

I have a view that call an alert that is another smaller view, whenever the second View is shown, I want to hide it when clicking outside of it.
How can I do that?

```
struct AlertView: View{

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    
    @Binding var alertIsShown: Bool

    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
            Button("Cancel") {
                self.alertIsShown=false
            }
                                
        }.padding()
            .frame(width: screenSize.width * 0.85, height: screenSize.height * 0.6)
            .background(Color(red: 0.4627, green: 0.8392, blue: 1.0))
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0, style: .continuous))
            .offset(y: alertIsShown ? 0 : screenSize.height)
            .animation(.spring())
            .shadow(color: Color(.white), radius: 6, x: -9, y: -0)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

For the main view that call the alert:

struct MainView: View {

```
@State private var alertIsShown = false
@State var liveOrdersList: [String] = ["item-1", "item-2"]

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        NavigationView{
            
            List{
                
                ForEach(liveOrdersList, id: \.self) { order in

                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Text("\(order.totalPrice)")
                            
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button("add") {
                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
                                alertIsShown.toggle()
                            }
                           
                        }        

                    }
                
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    }
    
    if alertIsShown{ //here I call the aler
        AlertView(alertIsShown: $alertIsShown)
    }
    
}
```

The list of buttons call the alert view.
How can I hide it when tapping outside of it?

Comment: I call the alert on the last lines of the main view, i added some comments. Its not calling the view, its more like show and hide back the view

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach, using `.simultaneousGesture(...)`, as shown in this example code, to hide the `AlertView` by touching anywhere outside of it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State var alertIsShown = false
    // for testing
    @State var liveOrdersList: [String] = ["item-1", "item-2", "item-3", "item-4", "item-5"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(liveOrdersList, id: \.self) { order in
                        HStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("\(order)")
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Button("add") {
                                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
                                    alertIsShown.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // -- here
                .simultaneousGesture(alertIsShown ? TapGesture().onEnded {
                    alertIsShown = false
                } : nil)
                
                if alertIsShown {
                    AlertView(alertIsShown: $alertIsShown)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this causing performance problem? becasue the views get very very laggy whenever I try this type of alert.. Is there another way to make it faster?

Comment: Is this causing performance problem in my code or your code?

Comment: This code, where I have the if alertIsShown

Comment: Cannot replicate this problem. Works well (very fast) for me on macos 13.1 Ventura, using Xcode 14.1, target macCatalyst and ios-16.
Tested on real devices, not Previews. It may be different on older systems.

Comment: Can you try please with my view? i think thats because of the performance

Comment: you need to show a working example code at a minimum, e.g what is `liveOrdersList` for example, where do you declare it, etc...

Comment: it some api call that gives me some list, i found that the problem is with `.shadow()`, do you know if this affects performance?

Comment: if you don't show the code that you are using, it is impossible to guess what you are doing. Edit your question, and show the code you are **really** using. Are you referring to the `.shadow` in the `AlertView`?

Comment: yes, in the alertview

Comment: I added you own list but its still slow..

Comment: I just cannot replicate this problem. Works well (very fast) for me, with or without the shadow, or animation or number of other things. In other code I sometimes add `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to the `NavigationView`, try it, maybe it will speed things for you.

Comment: I am using a 2015 macbook pro i7 16ram, should I try to simulate on a real device?

Comment: try it, I tested on real devices, not Previews, not simulators.

Comment: I am new at swift/xcode, real devices run faster than simulators?